# ¿Como puedo recorrer un json para posteriormente extraer los objetos con java?

Tags: java, json

este es mi json del cual quiero extraer "description", per no puedo recorrer el array que posee, soy nuevo trabajando con json, alguna idea de como hacerlo

```
"coord": {
    "lon": -70.65,
    "lat": -33.46

},
"weather": [
    {
        "id": 802,
        "main": "Clouds",
        "description": "nubes dispersas",
        "icon": "03d"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La librería org.json es fácil de usar. Aquí tienes un ejemplo de codigo:

```
import org.json.*;



JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("weather");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    String descripcion = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("description");
    ......
}
```

Puedes encontrar más ejemplo en: http://theoryapp.com/parse-json-in-java/

jar descargable: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

PD: Esta respuesta es una traducción de la dada en la versión inglesa, adaptada a tu caso. Espero que te haya servido: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java